# Iterator performance contract (and use on non-collections)

Tags: java, performance, iterator

If all that you're doing is a simple one-pass iteration (i.e. only `hasNext()` and `next()`, no `remove()`), are you guaranteed linear time performance and/or amortized constant cost per operation?

Is this specified in the `Iterator` contract anywhere?

Are there data structures/Java `Collection` which cannot be iterated in linear time?

`java.util.Scanner implements Iterator<String>`. A `Scanner` is hardly a data structure (e.g. `remove()` makes absolutely no sense). Is this considered a design blunder?

Is something like `PrimeGenerator implements Iterator<Integer>` considered bad design, or is this exactly what `Iterator` is for? (`hasNext()` always returns true, `next()` computes the next number on demand, `remove()` makes no sense).

Similarly, would it have made sense for `java.util.Random implements Iterator<Double>`?

Should a type really implement `Iterator` if it's effectively only using one-third of its API? (i.e. no `remove()`, always `hasNext()`)

Comment: no, no, yes/no(I *think*), no, looks fine by me, no since random can return a variety of next types - which one do you choose?, and finally: if you have something that would conveniently consume an iterator of that type and not need remove/hasNext, sure looks good to me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such guarantee. As you point out, anyone can model anything as Iterator. Individual producers of iterators would have to specify their individual performance.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in the [`Iterator` documentaton](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) mentions any kind of performance guarantee, so there is no guarantee.

It also wouldn't make sense to require this constraint on such a universal tool.

A much more useful constraint would be document a `iterator()` method to specify the time constraints that *this `Iterator` instance* fulfills (for example an `Iterator` over a general-purpose `Collection` will most likely be able to guarantee linear time operation).

Similarly, nothing in the documentation requires `hasNext()` to ever return `false`, so an endless `Iterator` would be perfectly valid.

However, there is a general assumption that all `Iterator` instances behave like "normal" `Iterator` instances as returned by `Collection.iterator()` in that they return some number of values and *end* at some point. This is not required by the documentation and, strictly speaking, any code depending on that fact would be subtly broken.

Answer (score 1):

All of your proposals sound reasonable for `Iterator`.  The API docs explicitly say `remove` need not be supported, and suggests that one not use the older `Enumeration` that works just like `Iterator` except without remove.

Also, infinite-length streams are a very useful concept in functional programming, and can be implemented with an `Iterator` that always `hasNext`.  It's a feature that it can handle either case.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're thinking of iterators in the sense of a list or set traversal. I think a more useful mental model is a discrete object stream, aything that you want to handle one-at-a-time that can be streamed from a source in terms of discrete instances.

In that sense a stream of prime numbers or of list objects both makes sense, and the model doesn't imply anything about the finite-ness of the data source.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a use case for this.. And it seems intuitive enough. Personally I think it's fine.

```
for(long prime : new PrimeGenerator()){
    //do stuff
    if(condition){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: not to mention that if(condition) *could* be represented in hasNext anyway - it just may be more convenient to code it as you have.