# More advanced usage of interfaces

Tags: java, interface, iterator, iteration

To be honest I'm not quite sure if I understand the task myself :) I was told to create class MySimpleIt, that implements Iterator and Iterable and will allow to run the provided test code. Arguments and variables of objects cannot be either Collections or arrays.
The code :

```
 MySimpleIt msi=new MySimple(10,100,
                           MySimpleIt.PRIME_NUMBERS);

 for(int el: msi)
   System.out.print(el+" ");    
 System.out.println();

 msi.setType(MySimpleIterator.ODD_NUMBERS);
 msi.setLimits(15,30);
 for(int el: msi)
   System.out.print(el+" ");    
 System.out.println();

 msi.setType(MySimpleIterator.EVEN_NUMBERS);
 for(int el: msi)
   System.out.print(el+" ");    
 System.out.println();
```

The result I should obtain :

```
11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 


15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 


16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
```

And here's my code :

```
import java.util.Iterator; 
interface MySimpleIterator{
    static int ODD_NUMBERS=0;
    static int EVEN_NUMBERS = 1;
    static int PRIME_NUMBERS = 2;

    int setType(int i);
}

public class MySimpleIt implements Iterable, Iterator, MySimpleIterator {    
    public MySimple my;

    public MySimpleIt(MySimple m){ 
        my = m;      
    }

    public int setType(int i){
        my.numbers = i;
        return my.numbers;
    }

    public void setLimits(int d, int u){
        my.down = d;
        my.up = u;
    }

    public Iterator iterator(){
        Iterator it = this.iterator();
        return it;
    }

    public void remove(){  
    }

    public Object next(){
        Object o = new Object();
        return o;
    }

    public boolean hasNext(){
        return true;
    }

}

class MySimple {
    public int down;
    public int up;
    public int numbers;

    public MySimple(int d, int u, int n){
        down = d;
        up = u;
        numbers = n;
    }
}
```

In the test code I have error in line when creating MySimpleIt msi object, as it finds MySimple instead of MySimpleIt. Also I have errors in for-each loops, because compiler wants 'ints' there instead of Object. Anyone has any idea on how to solve it ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use new MySimpleIt() rather than new MySimple()?

Comment: Looks like the test code uses 3 different names for what should be the same class : MySimple, MySimpleIt and MySimpleIterator.

Comment: This is an unusual request because SimpleIt is its own Iterator. So, your iterator() method should be returning 'this'. That should get you started, I recommend diving into a couple of the standard iterators and iterables to see how they work, once you understand the pattern all that's left is to fill the logic in the next() method to give you the right numbers (I'm pretty sure you can get primes out of the Java Math library which should make things very easy)

Comment: Don't make an object that is both Iterable and its own Iterator.

Comment: @Thilo He was specifically asked to do that.

Comment: Is his code missing the @Override on the iterator() method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty wrong with the design of this assignment.

#### Use `enum`

The test code contains this snippets:

```
MySimpleIt(erator?).PRIME_NUMBERS
MySimpleIt(erator?).ODD_NUMBERS
MySimpleIt(erator?).EVEN_NUMBERS
```

In one place the type is `MySimpleIt`, in another it's `MySimpleIterator`. Either way, the name suggests using an interface to define a bunch of constants. THIS IS NOT A PROPER USE OF an `interface`!!!

It would be a much better design to use an `enum` instead:

```
enum SequenceType {
  PRIME_NUMBERS, ODD_NUMBERS, EVEN_NUMBERS;
}
```

See: *Effective Java 2nd Edition* Item 30: Use enums instead of `int` constants.

---

#### Consider multiple implementations of the `interface` instead of a monolith with `setType`

It looks like your sequencer should be able to switch sequence type on a whim. This will result in that class being a huge blob that must know how to generate every type of sequences. It may work okay just for the 3 types given here, but it's definitely a poor design if you later want to add more types of sequences.

Consider just having different implementations of the same interface for the different types of sequences. You may want to define an `AbstractIntegerSequencer` that defines the basic functionality (resetting bounds, answering `hasNext()`, `iterator()`, etc), that delegates to an `abstract protected int generateNext()` for subclasses to `@Override`. This way, the specifics of the type of sequence to generate is nicely encapsulated to each subclass.

You can still keep `enum SequenceType` for a `static` factory method that instantiates these different subclasses, one for each sequence type, but those sequences themselves probably shouldn't be able to switch type on a whim.

---

#### Use generics

Instead of making your type `implements Iterator`, you should make it `implements Iterator<Integer>`.

From [JLS 4.8 Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/typesValues.html#4.8) (emphasis theirs):

> The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of genericity into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged. **It is possible that future versions of the Java programming language will disallow the use of raw types**.

See also *Effective Java 2nd Edition* Item 32: Don't use raw type in new code.

---

#### Don't confuse `Iterator<T>` with `Iterable<T>`.

Let's say you have something like this:

```
IntegerSequencer seq = new PrimeSequencer(0, 10);

for (int i : seq) {
  System.out.println(i);
} // prints "2", "3", "5", 7"

for (int i : seq) {
  System.out.println(i);
} // what should it print???
```

If you make `seq implements Iterable<Integer>, Iterator<Integer>` and `@Override Iterator<Integer> iterator()` to `return this;`, then the second loop wouldn't print anything, since `seq` is its own `iterator()`, and at that point there is no more `hasNext()` for `seq`.

A proper implementation of `Iterable<Integer>` should be able to generate as many independent `Iterator<Integer>` as necessary for the user, and such implementation would again print prime numbers between `0` and `10` in the above code.

---

#### Further readings on stackoverflow

- [Iterator performance contract (and use on non-collections)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501274/iterator-performance-contract-and-use-on-non-collections)

  - This question asked about `PrimeGenerator implements Iterator<Integer>` (among other things)
- [Why is Java’s Iterator not an Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839178/why-is-javas-iterator-not-an-iterable)
- [What is the Iterable interface used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059127/what-is-the-iterable-interface-used-for)
- [Why can't I iterate over an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598219/java-why-cant-iterate-over-an-iterator/)